# How to use Class range when coding in apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building a Slack Bot for my internship, and I can get it to send direct messages to a private channel, and connect through the API.
But my current problem is getting the algorithm to take the information in a spreadsheet and form a message with that data in the channel. I found a tutorial on youtube, and their code looks like this, I need to understand what this code is doing, please help!

```
function getLatestMetrics(){

    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID)
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(YOUR_SHEET_NAME)
    const latest_metrics = sheet.getRange(6,1,8,7).getValues();
    const metric_deltas = sheet.getRange(2,4,2,4).getValues();
    const metric_array_positions = {

      queries: 3,
      first_page: 4,
      impressions: 5,
      clicks: 6
    }

    const metrics = {
      period: {
        week: {
          start: Utilities.formatDate(latest_metrics[0][1],"EST", "yyyy-MM-dd"),
          end: Utilities.formatDate(latest_metrics[0][2],"EST", "yyyy-MM-dd")
        },

        month: {
          start: Utilities.formatDate(latest_metrics[3][1],"EST", "yyyy-MM-dd"),
          end: Utilities.formatDate(latest_metrics[0][2],"EST", "yyyy-MM-dd")
        }
      },

      queries: {
        this_week: latest_metrics[0][metric_array_positions.queries],
        last_week: latest_metrics[1][metric_array_positions.queries],
        this_month: sumSheetValues(latest_metrics, 0, 3, metric_array_positions.queries),
        last_month: sumSheetValues(latest_metrics, 4, 7, metric_array_positions.queries),
        wow_delta: Math.round(metric_deltas[0][0]*100) + '%',
        mom_delta: Math.round(metric_deltas[1][0]*100) + '%'
      },


      first_page: {
        this_week: latest_metrics[0][metric_array_positions.first_page],
        last_week: latest_metrics[1][metric_array_positions.first_page],
        this_month: sumSheetValues(latest_metrics, 0, 3, metric_array_positions.first_page),
        last_month: sumSheetValues(latest_metrics, 4, 7, metric_array_positions.first_page),
        wow_delta: Math.round(metric_deltas[0][1]*100) + '%',
        mom_delta: Math.round(metric_deltas[1][1]*100) + '%'
      },


      impressions: {
        this_week: latest_metrics[0][metric_array_positions.impressions],
        last_week: latest_metrics[1][metric_array_positions.impressions],
        this_month: sumSheetValues(latest_metrics, 0, 3, metric_array_positions.impressions),
        last_month: sumSheetValues(latest_metrics, 4, 7, metric_array_positions.impressions),
        wow_delta: Math.round(metric_deltas[0][2]*100) + '%',
        mom_delta: Math.round(metric_deltas[1][2]*100) + '%'
      },


      clicks: {
        this_week: latest_metrics[0][metric_array_positions.clicks],
        last_week: latest_metrics[1][metric_array_positions.clicks],
        this_month: sumSheetValues(latest_metrics, 0, 3, metric_array_positions.clicks),
        last_month: sumSheetValues(latest_metrics, 4, 7, metric_array_positions.clicks),
        wow_delta: Math.round(metric_deltas[0][3]*100) + '%',
        mom_delta: Math.round(metric_deltas[1][3]*100) + '%'
      }
    }
    return metrics
}
function sumSheetValues(data, array_row_start, array_row_end, array_column) {
    let result = 0
    for(let i = array_row_start; i <= array_row_end; i++) {
      result += data[i][array_column]
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please start by reading https://develpers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Getting data from Spreadsheet and iterating over it

```
function getSpreadsheetData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
  vs.forEach((row,i) => {
    //iterate through rows
    row.forEach((col,j) => {
      //iterate through columns
    })
  })
}
```

Data:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 3 | 19 | 14 | 5 |
| 9 | 6 | 15 | 4 | 15 |
| 13 | 7 | 9 | 14 | 6 |
| 17 | 17 | 7 | 11 | 0 |
| 16 | 4 | 18 | 14 | 17 |

```
Execution log
7:44:48 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:44:49 AM  Info    [[12,3,19,14,5],[9,6,15,4,15],[13,7,9,14,6],[17,17,7,11,0],[16,4,18,14,17]]
7:44:50 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: What "const ss=", "const vs", "const sh" means?

Comment: @fernanda This means that a variable is being declared for later used in the code. I'd kindly suggest you review this codelab that goes over the fundamentals and will help you understand the code and Cooper's answer https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1#3